# gdaldem slope....odd values, almost all 89.98+/- (? - why?)

Tags: slope, gdaldem

I'm passing an SRTM1 3601x3601 file to "gdaldem slope".....I've queried the values in Python, they are reasonable (min 222, max 424) for an area of SW Iowa.  Took a bit to get the syntax right, but file is being created all right.  Oddly though, almost all cells have a value from say 89.95 to 89.99, with a few having zeros (and the borders, no surprise / no problem, 9999).  Looking at the 0's, it is when the elevation is flat, say for a water body.

Default slope is supposed to be degrees; anyone have any idea why I am getting the ~89.9x values?

Comment: sorry my imprecision if it is not clear; the 222-424 elevation values are from the raw SRTM1, and the odd 89.9X + several zeros values are in the gdaldem slope output file......

Comment: It is because your horizontal units (X, Y) are decimal degrees and your vertical units are metres and you didn't use the `-s scale` in your `gdaldem` command.